# Run As Administrator Prompt PID

Tags: windows, command-prompt, pid

When run a exe file as administrator, Windows prompts Run As Administrator prompt and if select Yes process runs as an admin user but when prompt shows i want to kill Run As Administrator prompt like nothing happens.
What is Run As Administrator PID and how can i kill it without select Yes or No.

Comment: It would be a security flaw if the prompt was able to be manipulated as you describe.

Comment: It's unclear from your question if your attempting to be evil by having the app elevated without the user's consent of if you want it to run un-elevated. Assuming good intentions, I'd be surprised if there wasn't some setting you can set in the application's manifest to achieve this. Assuming bad intentions, I'd be stunned if there was.